# What is the meaning of exclamation '!' in shell scripting?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

```
if [[ ! -d /home/pp ]] 
then
    print "$0 Directory /home/pp doesn't exist"
    return 1
fi
```

What is the meaning of `!`, `$0` and `return 1` here?

Answer (score 4):

this means if `/home/pp/` is **not** (`!`) a **directory** (`-d`) then the script will print `Directory doesn't exist` and exits with 1 which means error

**( any exit other than 0 means error )**

and the `$0` means the script name
example

`./script a b c`

```
$0 will print 'script'
$1 will print 'a'
$2 will print 'b'
$3 will print 'c'
```

Comment: $0 is the script name and $1 is the first pattern.

Answer (score 2):

- **!** is not
- **$0** is the argument holding the script name
- **return 1** is a return code to be interpreted by a calling program. 1 indicates an
  error.

Comment: $0 is the name of the script

Comment: And for a bit of clarity, any non zero return value indicates an error

Answer (score 2):

It has a meaning similar to it's meaning in C: "not" or logical negation. In this case, you can parse it into pseudocode as `not(directory-exists(/home/pp))`.